# PHP OPcache crashes when having multiple patterns in blacklist file

Tags: php, regex, apache, blacklist, opcache

I have OPcache configured in my `php.ini` file as follows:

```
[opcache]
zend_extension="C:\xampp-5.6\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.save_comments=0
opcache.load_comments=0
opcache.blacklist_filename="C:\xampp-5.6\php\cfg\opcache.blacklist"
```

If there is just one file pattern inside the blacklist file, everything works fine. But as soon as I add another file pattern for another directory, Apache aborts the startup process and OPcache emits the following error message:

```
Fri Sep 18 10:15:48 2015 (8684): Debug Loading blacklist file:  'C:\xampp-5.6\php\cfg\opcache.blacklist'
Fri Sep 18 10:15:48 2015 (8684): Error Blacklist compilation: empty (sub)expression
```

The blacklist file that makes it crash looks as follows:

```
C:\xampp-5.6\htdocs\Application1\rbac\*
C:\xampp-5.6\htdocs\Application2\rbac\*
```

- I tried different line ending styles: Windows and UNIX
- There is always at least one file inside these directories
- The error message hints towards a faulty regular expression, but OPcache documentation says, that wildcards are allowed.
- I also tried escaping the backslashes and use `.*` instead of just `*`

None of these attempts changed anything. If I apply any of these changes to a single-line file, Apache keeps starting normally. But as soon as there is a second line (comments as a second line are working, though) in the blacklist file, Apache aborts startup.

What is wrong with this blacklist file and how can I get it to work with multiple directories/patterns?

Comment: Did you try to add double quotes ? like "C:\xampp-5.6\htdocs\Application1\rbac\*" ?

Comment: @Fky Just tried it, but OPcache still produces the same error message.

Comment: I think it's xampp who browse your directories , try this : 
C:/xampp-5\.6/htdocs/Application2/rbac/*

Comment: @Fky Sorry, doesn't work either.